# Creating a function where on collision enemy will be slow and after a set amount of time it reverts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello my code is basically on collision it will start the coroutine of slowing the enemy then after 3.2 seconds it reverts back to original.

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
     if (collision.tag == "slowProjectile")
    {
        StartCoroutine(slowEnemy());
    }
}

// FROZEN ENEMY BEHAVIOUR
public bool isFrozen = true;
IEnumerator slowEnemy()
{
    if (isFrozen == true)
    {
        isFrozen = false;
        Debug.Log("FROZEN");
        // Turns the enemy into color blue
        this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.blue;
        enemyMovementSpeed = enemyMovementSpeed / 2;

        // waits for 3.2 seconds 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.2f);

        // Then return the enemy movement speed and color to its original state.
        enemyMovementSpeed = enemyMovementSpeed * 2;
        this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;     
    }
    else
    {
        isFrozen = true;
    }
}
```

problem is the coroutine is stacking meaning it will run x2 and lost the original value also the projectile fires every 3 seconds. Think of it as A shooter that shoots every 3 seconds and on impact slows the enemy for 3 seconds. ( Like a Snow Pea if you play Plants Vs Zombie )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if what you want is `the Frozen effect doesn't stack` :

```
public bool isFrozen = false;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "slowProjectile")
    {
        if (!isFrozen)
        {
            StartCoroutine(slowEnemy());
        } 
    }
}

IEnumerator slowEnemy()
{
    isFrozen = true;
        
    Debug.Log("FROZEN");
    // Turns the enemy into color blue
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.blue;
    enemyMovementSpeed = enemyMovementSpeed / 2;

    // waits for 3.2 seconds 
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.2f);

    // Then return the enemy movement speed and color to its original state.
    enemyMovementSpeed = enemyMovementSpeed * 2;
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;  
        
    isFrozen = false;
}
```

The downside of the code above is that `while the Speed Change doesn't stack, the Frozen Time neither`.

If you want to `stack the Frozen Time and not stack Speed Change at the same time`, maybe you need to add a `Forzen Stack Counter` to check whether the Frozen time is ended :

```
public int forenStackCount = 0;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "slowProjectile")
    {          
        StartCoroutine(slowEnemy());
    }
}

private IEnumerator slowEnemy()
{
    if (forenStackCount == 0)
    {
        StartFrozenEffect();
    }

    forenStackCount++;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.2f);

    forenStackCount--;

    if (forenStackCount == 0)
    {
        EndFrozenEffect();
    }
}

private void StartFrozenEffect()
{
    Debug.Log("FROZEN");
    // Turns the enemy into color blue
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.blue;
    enemyMovementSpeed = enemyMovementSpeed / 2;
}

private void EndFrozenEffect()
{
    enemyMovementSpeed = enemyMovementSpeed * 2;
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answer is right but adds many coroutines. Here is a solution that uses only one coroutine at a time.

```
private float m_timer;
private IEnumerator m_coroutine;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "slowProjectile")
    {  
        m_timer = 0f;
        if (m_coroutine == null){
             m_coroutine = FreezeTime();
             StartCoroutine(m_coroutine);
        }        
    }
}

IEnumerator FreezeTime()
{
    while (m_timer < 3.2f){
         m_timer += Time.deltaTime;
         yield return null;
    }
    m_coroutine = null;
}
```

When a collision occurs, reset to 0 and if no coroutine is already running, create a new one.

The coroutine keeps increasing the timer, if a collision occurs, it will reset to 0. When done, it resets the coroutine reference.

Comment: Clever solution. I think to make it more completed, you should add `StartFrozenEffect()` at the start of `FreezeTime()` and `EndFrozenEffect()` at the end of it.